# Delete Field in Datatable with ajax in Codeiginiter without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I want to delete some field in datatable using 'a' tag as a button. If that button is pressed, it will delete field in my database using ajax without refreshing page but if i click the button, it doesn't do anything. I am weak in JS or jQuery, I hope you guys will help me, thanks.

**This is my JS**

```
$('#delete-agenda').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {};
    data['id_itenerary'] = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/pandansari/admin/single_trip/delete_agenda',
        type: 'post',
        data: data
    });
});
```

**This is my 'a' tag**

```
<a id="delete-agenda" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="<?php echo $agenda['id_itenerary'] ?>">Delete</a>
```

**This is my controller function**

```
public function delete_agenda() {
    $id_itenerary = $this->input->post('id_itenerary');
    $this->agenda_model->delete_agenda($id_itenerary);
}
```

**This is my model function**

```
public function delete_agenda($id_itenerary) {
    $this->db->where('id_itenerary', $id_itenerary);
    $this->db->delete('tb_itenerary');
}
```

Comment: for debugging. add this line in click event `alert($(this).attr('value'));` also check console error..

Comment: i've tried to add alert function like you've said, but it still do nothing. also nothing display in console log, maybe any wrong spelling or whatever in my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

HTML:

```
<a id="delete-agenda" href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="<?php echo $agenda['id_itenerary'] ?>">Delete</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#delete-agenda').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/pandansari/admin/single_trip/delete_agenda',
            type: 'post',
            data: { 'id_itenerary' : id }
        });
    });
});
```

You will still have to remove the datatable entry from the table; otherwise the change will only be apparent on refresh/reload.

Comment: so how if i want to refresh the same page after the process done? thanks.

Comment: first, did this address your question? is the item deleting from the database?

Comment: i've tried your solutions. but why the e.preventDefault() is not work. thats the whole point. it still did href, it did href to #, which is only bring to the first document

Comment: e.preventDefault() always works. you must not be loading the js script properly, or you are missing jquery. check the console for errors, check the network pane for failed requests.

Comment: idk, i put the js script in footer, after i link jquery. and another jquery function is work properly, only if i use e.pereventDefault it doesn't work, and still do the default action of html tag

Comment: i can't diagnose something without some troubleshooting on your end.

Comment: i already success to delete the field with ajax, but as u explain before. it still need to refresh the page first to view the change. how can i view the change without refreshing page? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#delete-agenda').on('submit',function(e){
```

e.preventDefault();
//write your remaining code here

});

Comment: sorry sir, but i use a link instead of a form, so i think on submit will do nothing